# How to automate deployment to ECS Fargate when new image is pushed to ECR repository

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

Firstly, this is specific to CDK - I know there are plenty of questions/answers around this topic out there but none of them are CDK specific.

Given that best practices dictate that a Fargate deployment shouldn't look for the 'latest' tag in an ECR repository, how could one set up a CDK pipeline when using ECR as a source?

In a multi-repository application where each service is in it's own repository (where those repositories would have their own CDK CodeBuild deployments to set up building and pushing to ECR), how would the infrastructure CDK pipeline be aware of new images being pushed to an ECR repository and be able to deploy that new image to the ECS Fargate service?

Since a task definition has to specify an image tag (else it'll look for 'latest' which may not exist), this seems to be impossible.

As a concrete example, say I have the following 2 repositories:

- CdkInfra

  - One of these repositories would be created for each customer to create the full environment for their application
- SomeService

  - Actual application code
  - Only one of this repository should exist and re-used by multiple CdkInfra projects
  - `cdk` directory defining the CodeBuild project so when a push to master is detected, the service is built and the image pushed to ECR

The expected workflow would be as such:

1. SomeService repository is updated and so a new image is pushed to ECR
2. The CdkInfra pipeline should detect that a tracked ECR repository has a new image
3. The CdkInfra pipeline updates the Fargate task definition to reference the new image's tag
4. The Fargate service pulls the new image and deploys it

I know there is currently a limit with CodeDeploy not supporting ECS deployments due to CFN not supporting them, but it seems that CodePipelineActions has the ability to set up an EcrSourceAction which may be able to achieve this, however I've been unable to get this to work so far.

Is this possible at all, or am I stuck waiting until CFN support ECS CodeDeploy functionality?

Comment: Use the SDK to fetch the value of an SSM parameter from your CDK code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so after some hackery I've managed to do this.

Firstly, the service itself (in this case it's a Spring Boot project) gets a `cdk` directory in it's root. This basically just sets up the CI part of the CI/CD pipeline:

```js
const appName: string = this.node.tryGetContext('app-name');

const ecrRepo = new ecr.Repository(this, `${appName}Repository`, {
    repositoryName: appName,
    imageScanOnPush: true,
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
});

const bbSource = codebuild.Source.bitBucket({
    // BitBucket account
    owner: 'mycompany',
    // Name of the repository this project belongs to
    repo: 'reponame',
    // Enable webhook
    webhook: true,
    // Configure so webhook only fires when the master branch has an update to any code other than this CDK project (e.g. Spring source only)
    webhookFilters: [codebuild.FilterGroup.inEventOf(codebuild.EventAction.PUSH).andBranchIs('master').andFilePathIsNot('./cdk/*')],
});

const buildSpec = {
    version: '0.2',
    phases: {
        pre_build: {
            // Get the git commit hash that triggered this build
            commands: ['env', 'export TAG=${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION}'],
        },
        build: {
            commands: [
                // Build Java project
                './mvnw clean install -Dskiptests',
                // Log in to ECR repository that contains the Corretto image
                'aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 489478819445.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                // Build docker images and tag them with the commit hash as well as 'latest'
                'docker build -t $ECR_REPO_URI:$TAG -t $ECR_REPO_URI:latest .',
                // Log in to our own ECR repository to push
                '$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)',
                // Push docker images to ECR repository defined above
                'docker push $ECR_REPO_URI:$TAG',
                'docker push $ECR_REPO_URI:latest',
            ],
        },
        post_build: {
            commands: [
                // Prepare the image definitions artifact file
                'printf \'[{"name":"servicename","imageUri":"%s"}]\' $ECR_REPO_URI:$TAG > imagedefinitions.json',
                'pwd; ls -al; cat imagedefinitions.json',
            ],
        },
    },
    // Define the image definitions artifact - is required for deployments by other CDK projects
    artifacts: {
        files: ['imagedefinitions.json'],
    },
};

const buildProject = new codebuild.Project(this, `${appName}BuildProject`, {
    projectName: appName,
    source: bbSource,
    environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_3,
        privileged: true,
        environmentVariables: {
            // Required for tagging/pushing image
            ECR_REPO_URI: { value: ecrRepo.repositoryUri },
        },
    },
    buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(buildSpec),
});

!!buildProject.role &&
    buildProject.role.addToPrincipalPolicy(
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['ecr:*'],
            resources: ['*'],
        }),
    );
```

Once this is set up, the CodeBuild project has to be built manually once so the ECR repo has a valid 'latest' image (otherwise the ECS service won't get created correctly).

Now in the separate infrastructure codebase you can create the ECS cluster and service as normal, getting the ECR repository from a lookup:

```js
const repo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, 'SomeRepository', 'reponame'); // reponame here has to match what you defined in the bbSource previously

const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, `Cluster`, { vpc });

const service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'Service', {
    cluster,
    serviceName: 'servicename',
    taskImageOptions: {
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repo, 'latest'),
        containerName: repo.repositoryName,
        containerPort: 8080,
    },
});
```

Finally create a deployment construct which listens to ECR events, manually converts the generated imageDetail.json file into a valid imagedefinitions.json file, then deploys to the existing service.

```js
const sourceOutput = new cp.Artifact();
const ecrAction = new cpa.EcrSourceAction({
    actionName: 'ECR-action',
    output: sourceOutput,
    repository: repo, // this is the same repo from where the service was originally defined
});

const buildProject = new codebuild.Project(this, 'BuildProject', {
    environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_3,
        privileged: true,
    },
    buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
            build: {
                commands: [
                    'cat imageDetail.json | jq "[. | {name: .RepositoryName, imageUri: .ImageURI}]" > imagedefinitions.json',
                    'cat imagedefinitions.json',
                ],
            },
        },
        artifacts: {
            files: ['imagedefinitions.json'],
        },
    }),
});

const convertOutput = new cp.Artifact();
const convertAction = new cpa.CodeBuildAction({
    actionName: 'Convert-Action',
    input: sourceOutput,
    outputs: [convertOutput],
    project: buildProject,
});

const deployAction = new cpa.EcsDeployAction({
    actionName: 'Deploy-Action',
    service: service.service,
    input: convertOutput,
});

new cp.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
    stages: [
        { stageName: 'Source', actions: [ecrAction] },
        { stageName: 'Convert', actions: [convertAction] },
        { stageName: 'Deploy', actions: [deployAction] },
    ],
});
```

Obviously this isn't as clean as it otherwise could be once CloudFormation supports this fully, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the name of the latest tag in an [AWS Systems Manager (SSM)](https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/home) [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) (see the list [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/parameters/)), and dynamically update it when you deploy new images to ECR.

Then, you could use the AWS **S**DK to fetch the value of the parameter during your CDK deploy, and then pass that value to your Fargate deployment.

The following CDK stack written in Python uses the value of the `YourSSMParameterName` parameter (in my AWS account) as the name of an S3 bucket:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core as cdk
    aws_s3 as s3
)

import boto3

class MyStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope, construct_id, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    
        res = ssm.get_parameter(Name='YourSSMParameterName')
        name = res['Parameter']['Value']

        s3.Bucket(
            self, '...',
            bucket_name=name,
        )
```

I tested that and it worked beautifully.

Comment: If I update the application repository to add/update the parameter when the image is pushed, and update the main stack to pull the value from the store, how would I set up a trigger to recognise that the parameter value has changed, and so the deployment needs to occur?

Comment: @AndreiSevtsenko I think in the current state of affairs, the best you can do is work with lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

My view on this situation is that if you are using CDK (actually is CloudFormation) to deploy latest image from ECR is very difficult.

What I end up is putting all Docker image build and CDK deploy as a one build script

In my case, is a Java application, I build the war file and prepare the DockerFile in a /docker directory

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
COPY deploy.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Then have the CDK script to pick up and build the image in Runtime.

```js
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, 'taskDefinition', {
      cpu: 256,
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024
    });
   
    const container = taskDefinition.addContainer('web', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(
        new DockerImageAsset(this, "image", {
          directory: "docker"
        })
      )
    });
```

This will put the image into a specific CDK ECR repository and deploy.

Therefore, I don't relies on the ECR for keeping different version of my build. Each time I need to deploy or rollback, just do it directly from the build script.